# returning JsonDoc as a reference from a method

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have the following method which gives out a jsonDoc as a reference

```
bool MyClass::jsonTest(rapidjson::Document & rjsonDoc)
{
    rjsonDoc.SetObject();
    rapidjson::Value val(rapidjson::kObjectType);
    val.AddMember("a", 1, rjsonDoc.GetAllocator());
    val.AddMember("b", 2, rjsonDoc.GetAllocator());
    val.AddMember("c", 3, rjsonDoc.GetAllocator());
    rjsonDoc.AddMember("Values", val, rjsonDoc.GetAllocator());

    //outputs the json into a file
    std::FILE* fp = fopen("outputjsonTest.json", "wb"); // non-Windows use "w"
    char writeBuffer[65536];
    rapidjson::FileWriteStream os(fp, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::FileWriteStream> writer(os);
    rjsonDoc.Accept(writer);
    fclose(fp);

    return false;
}
```

The above method when called writes a perfect json into the file outputjsonTest.json

But upon calling the method in another class and writing it into the file,

```
rapidjson::Document d;
CData_BisconaCtrl dMan;
dMan.jsonTest(d);
//outputs the json into a file
        std::FILE* fp = fopen("outputruntest.json", "wb"); // non-Windows use "w"
char writeBuffer[65536];
rapidjson::FileWriteStream os(fp, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::FileWriteStream> writer(os);
d.Accept(writer);
fclose(fp);
```

The file, outputruntest.json turns out to be blank.

It seems I cannot use the pass by reference style to return a jsonDocument from a method. Or am I making a mistake? Is it possible to return a jsonDocument in this way, at all?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with what you are doing.  Moreover, I tried running your code and it seemed to work for me.

That said, you should note that if you try to use the `Writer` more than once (e.g., to print more than one document or to print the same document a second time), you'll need to `Reset()` it, first.  It will stop producing output at the end of the first document, so if you try to print a second one it won't produce any output (because the result would not be a legal JSON "document").

[Edit:]
Nevertheless, rather than dumping the object to a file, you could try interrogating it to see what's in it.  Check its type, size, capacity; see if it has the expected members, or iterate over its members/entries; etc.  Failing all that, I would try proving that the basic C++ stuff is working.  (I.e.:  Is the right method actually being called?  Are there any unexpected exceptions which are being handled?  Is the method receiving the object that you're sending?  Etc.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the input. the writer was just a way to display the code. I internally have some other methods to display the json and even that fails as I get an empty json document when calling the jsonTest method.